# Fails to crop video with ratio height = width using FFMpeg on Android 7

Tags: android, ffmpeg, video-processing, android-ffmpeg

I am using FFMpeg Android [this link](https://github.com/writingminds/ffmpeg-android-java) in our Android app

**crop the video to 1:1 ratio i.e height = width**

The below command works great on Android devices with **Api < 24** but **Fails on Api 24**. I have also pasted my log analysis below, appreciate if anyone can help me fixing this issue.

```
public static String cropVideo(final Context context, final File file, final BaseCaptureInterface mBaseCaptureListener) {
    String croppedUrl = "";
    FFmpeg ffmpeg = FFmpeg.getInstance(context.getApplicationContext());
    try {
        croppedUrl = file.getParent() + "/Cropped_" + file.getName();
        String[] cmds = {"-i", file.getAbsolutePath(), "-vf", "crop=out_h=in_w", "-threads", "5", "-preset" ,"ultrafast","-strict","-2",croppedUrl};

        ffmpeg.execute(cmds, new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onStart() {
                Log.d(TAG, "cropVideo:onStart()");
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgress(String message) {
                Log.d(TAG, "cropVideo:onProgress(): " + message);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(String message) {
                Log.d(TAG, "cropVideo:onFailure(): " + message);
                Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to Crop the video", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String message) {
                file.delete();
                mBaseCaptureListener.videoCropStatus(true);
                Log.d(TAG, "cropVideo:onSuccess(): " + message);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                Log.d(TAG, "cropVideo:onFinish()");
            }
        });
    } catch (FFmpegCommandAlreadyRunningException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "cropVideo:error: " + e);
    }
    return croppedUrl;
}
```

Observation: Below is the comparison of Pass and Fail logs during onProgress() of cropping. in Fail Logs, the frame initial is 0 and then abruptly jumps to 2392 also the size increases proportionately. Whereas in the Pass logs, the increase in frame and size is quite smooth. 
I am wondering if my command string[] needs some changes. Please, let me know if you have any suggestions.

Pass Logs:

```
 Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
 frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.00 bitrate=   0.4kbits/s speed=1.97x    
 frame=   18 fps= 18 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.34 bitrate=   0.3kbits/s dup=9 drop=0 speed=1.33x    
 frame=   26 fps= 17 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:02.00 bitrate=   0.2kbits/s dup=13 drop=0 speed=1.33x    
 frame=   48 fps= 18 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:02.00 bitrate=   0.2kbits/s dup=24 drop=0 speed=0.744x    
 frame=   48 fps= 15 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:02.60 bitrate=   0.1kbits/s dup=24 drop=0 speed=0.814x    
 frame=   58 fps= 15 q=29.0 size=      25kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=  68.1kbits/s dup=29 drop=0 speed=0.802x    
 frame=   62 fps= 14 q=29.0 size=      45kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate= 122.6kbits/s dup=31 drop=0 speed=0.679x    
 frame=   68 fps= 14 q=29.0 size=      68kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate= 184.3kbits/s dup=34 drop=0 speed=0.608x    
 frame=   74 fps= 13 q=29.0 size=      96kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate= 262.1kbits/s dup=37 drop=0 speed=0.534x    
 frame=   79 fps= 13 q=29.0 size=     119kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate= 324.3kbits/s dup=39 drop=0 speed=0.482x   
frame=   81 fps= 12 q=29.0 size=     131kB time=00:00:03.20 bitrate= 335.2kbits/s dup=40 drop=0 speed=0.475x   
 frame=   81 fps= 11 q=29.0 size=     131kB time=00:00:03.98 bitrate= 268.9kbits/s dup=40 drop=0 speed=0.551x   
 frame=   92 fps= 12 q=29.0 size=     197kB time=00:00:04.01 bitrate= 402.0kbits/s dup=45 drop=0 speed=0.516x   
 frame=   96 fps= 11 q=29.0 size=     222kB time=00:00:04.01 bitrate= 452.9kbits/s dup=47 drop=0 speed=0.479x   
 frame=  101 fps= 11 q=29.0 size=     245kB time=00:00:04.01 bitrate= 499.8kbits/s dup=49 drop=0 speed=0.44x    
 frame=  105 fps= 11 q=29.0 size=     268kB time=00:00:04.01 bitrate= 546.6kbits/s dup=51 drop=0 speed=0.414x  
 frame=  112 fps= 11 q=29.0 size=     310kB time=00:00:04.09 bitrate= 620.0kbits/s dup=54 drop=0 speed= 0.4x    
 frame=  115 fps= 10 q=29.0 size=     326kB time=00:00:04.09 bitrate= 652.1kbits/s dup=55 drop=0 speed=0.374x  
 frame=  119 fps= 10 q=29.0 size=     355kB time=00:00:04.09 bitrate= 710.8kbits/s dup=57 drop=0 speed=0.355x  
 frame=  119 fps=7.1 q=-1.0 Lsize=     671kB time=00:00:04.13 bitrate=1327.9kbits/s dup=57 drop=0 speed=0.245x
 video:604kB audio:62kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.717086%
 [libx264 @ 0xb5b08800] frame I:1     Avg QP:23.35  size: 24768


Fail Logs:

   Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
 Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
 frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.81 bitrate=   0.5kbits/s speed=1.61x    
 frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.57 bitrate=   0.2kbits/s speed=1.56x    
 frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:02.30 bitrate=   0.2kbits/s speed=1.51x    
 frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:03.22 bitrate=   0.1kbits/s speed=1.58x    
 frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:04.13 bitrate=   0.1kbits/s speed=1.63x    
 frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:04.90 bitrate=   0.1kbits/s speed=1.61x    
 frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:05.82 bitrate=   0.1kbits/s speed=1.64x    
 frame= 2392 fps=111 q=22.0 size=    1059kB time=00:01:19.61 bitrate= 109.0kbits/s dup=2389 drop=0 speed=3.68x    
 frame= 2416 fps=109 q=27.0 size=    1059kB time=00:01:20.41 bitrate= 107.9kbits/s dup=2390 drop=0 speed=3.63x    
 frame= 2438 fps=108 q=27.0 size=    1059kB time=00:01:21.14 bitrate= 106.9kbits/s dup=2390 drop=0 speed=3.58x    
 frame= 2462 fps=106 q=26.0 size=    1060kB time=00:01:21.94 bitrate= 105.9kbits/s dup=2393 drop=0 speed=3.54x    
 frame= 2484 fps=105 q=25.0 size=    1060kB time=00:01:22.68 bitrate= 105.0kbits/s dup=2395 drop=0 speed= 3.5x    
 frame= 2506 fps=104 q=24.0 size=    1060kB time=00:01:23.41 bitrate= 104.1kbits/s dup=2397 drop=0 speed=3.45x    
 frame= 2530 fps=103 q=26.0 size=    1060kB time=00:01:24.21 bitrate= 103.1kbits/s dup=2397 drop=0 speed=3.41x    
 frame= 2554 fps=101 q=25.0 size=    1061kB time=00:01:25.01 bitrate= 102.2kbits/s dup=2399 drop=0 speed=3.38x    
 frame= 2577 fps=100 q=26.0 size=    1167kB time=00:01:25.78 bitrate= 111.4kbits/s dup=2399 drop=0 speed=3.34x    
 frame= 2588 fps= 99 q=-1.0 Lsize=    4707kB time=00:01:26.35 bitrate= 446.6kbits/s dup=2399 drop=0 speed=3.32x    
 video:4590kB audio:101kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.346620%
```

Comment: Share the full fail log.

Comment: @Mulvya you can find full fail logs here
https://gist.github.com/BabuinGH/dbbc36899b372468d0df26105d969544

Comment: @Mulvya , do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Can u add your gradle file

Comment: Have you got the solution

Comment: @AmjadKhan, Yes, I got it working. In my case, the library I'm using to record custom video was creating a bad video file. After correcting that and the same ffmpeg commands as I mentioned above is working fine.

Comment: @Babs Since you figured out the problem you should add the solution as an answer.